# on using oracle database link theres an error "ORA-12154 TNS Could not resolve the connect identifier specified"

Tags: oracle, database-link

I'm trying to define a database link on oracle 10.2 with connection identifier that throws the error in the question header.
I have the connection identifier (service name) in my tnsnames.ora file.
I can connect with sqlplus using this service name. no problem.
This is the creation sql:

create database link dev1.REGRESS.RDBMS.DEV.US.ORACLE.COM
  connect to user1 identified by pass1
  using 'dev1';

select using the link:
select * from t_users@dev1;

I get: ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified

connecting to oracle with sqlplus to the 'unidentified' service (with no problem):
sqlplus user1/pass1@dev1

I defined another link to the same database I'm woking in (loopback) - works OK.

I read and tried anything I could find about the subject but did not solve this.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you configure SQLNET? If you're using Local naming you may have to add tnsnames to the NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH in your Oracle Net Profile. You should post both your tnsnames and sqlnet files.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
create database link dev1 connect to user1 identified by pass1 using 'dev1';
```

Also note that a tnsnames.ora entry for `dev1` has to exist on the database server that you're linking from.

Comment: It's so obvious I'm quite ashamed I didn't think of it. The tnsnames I refered to was of course on my workstation. Thank you very much.